# Spectrum of unbounded operators

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am currently a little bit confused. I am aware of a theorem that says that any closed and densely defined operator satisfies $\sigma(T^*)=\overline{\sigma(T)}.$

On the other hand, the operator

$$T: H_0^1([0,1]) \subset L^2([0,1]) \rightarrow L^2([0,1]), f \mapsto if'$$

has the adjoint operator

$$T^*: H^1([0,1]) \subset L^2([0,1]) \rightarrow L^2([0,1]), f \mapsto if'.$$

The first one (T) has empty spectrum while its adjoint $T^*$ has $\sigma(T^*)=\mathbb{C}.$ Despite, both operator are closed and densely defined, so somehow this result is not reconcilable with the theorem I just stated. Is the theorem wrong or my example?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first operator $T$ does not have empty spectrum. To see why, suppose you want to solve $(T-\lambda I)f=g$ for $f \in H_{0}^{1}$. Then
$$
               if'-\lambda f=g \\
                   f'+i\lambda f =-i g\\
                 (e^{i\lambda t}f)' = -ie^{i\lambda t}g \\
             \int_{0}^{1}(e^{i\lambda t}f)'dt = -i\int_{0}^{1}e^{i\lambda t}g(t)dt \\
          0=e^{i\lambda t}f|_{0}^{1} = -i\int_{0}^{1}e^{i\lambda t}g(t)dt
$$
Therefore, there is no chance of solving the above unless $(g,e^{-i\lambda t})=0$. That means the range of $T-\lambda I$ is always deficient, for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, which means $\sigma(T)=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: ah right, I was only thinking in terms of eigenvalues, stupid me.

Comment: @user167575 It takes a while to figure out what tools you can use, and what you can't use. For example, $\mathcal{N}(T^{\star})=\mathcal{R}(T)^{\perp}$. I heard one distinguished Professor in the field say this: Unbounded operators are much easier to study because there are only a handful of results that you can use, and most of them are due to von Neumann; so you can try them all, and if nothing works, you can quit.